# Apache Ignite: getting the error: Getting affinity for topology version earlier than affinity is calculated

Tags: ignite

I'm running an Apache Ignite .Net 2.7 cluster in the Linux environment in a Kubernetes cluster. The Ignite cluster consists of 5 Ignite nodes running three microservices (2x1st service, 2x2nd service and 1 3rd service). Two of the microservices deploy a couple of Ignite services which call each other.

The cluster start up successfully, discovery works fine and all the nodes are being added into the cluster. But out of the sudden, both instances of a service (2 nodes) fail with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Getting affinity for topology version earlier than affinity is calculated [locNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=76308a3b-221a-4307-b181-bd4e66d82683, addrs=[10.0.0.62, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, product-service-deployment-7dd5496d58-l426m/10.0.0.62:47500], discPort=47500, order=8, intOrder=6, lastExchangeTime=1560283011887, loc=true, ver=2.7.0#20181130-sha1:256ae401, isClient=false], grp=ignite-sys-cache, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=17, minorTopVer=0], head=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=18, minorTopVer=0], history=[AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=9, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=11, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=11, minorTopVer=1], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=12, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=14, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=18, minorTopVer=0]]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityAssignmentCache.cachedAffinity(GridAffinityAssignmentCache.java:712)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityAssignmentCache.nodes(GridAffinityAssignmentCache.java:612)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAffinityManager.nodesByPartition(GridCacheAffinityManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAffinityManager.primaryByPartition(GridCacheAffinityManager.java:266)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAffinityManager.primaryByKey(GridCacheAffinityManager.java:257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAffinityManager.primaryByKey(GridCacheAffinityManager.java:281)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$TopologyListener$1.run0(GridServiceProcessor.java:1877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$DepRunnable.run(GridServiceProcessor.java:2064)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This causes the other service to fail because it depends on the first service:

```
Unhandled Exception: Apache.Ignite.Core.Services.ServiceInvocationException: Proxy method invocation failed with an exception. Examine InnerException for details. ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Failed to find deployed service: ProductService ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to find deployed service: ProductService
```

Since the second service is being restarted by Kubernetes, the first service reports constant topology changes:

```
[19:57:14] Topology snapshot [ver=20, locNode=76308a3b, servers=4, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=6.2GB, heap=2.0GB]
[19:57:15] Topology snapshot [ver=21, locNode=76308a3b, servers=5, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=5, offheap=7.8GB, heap=2.5GB]
[19:57:17] Topology snapshot [ver=22, locNode=76308a3b, servers=4, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=6.2GB, heap=2.0GB]
[19:57:49] Topology snapshot [ver=23, locNode=76308a3b, servers=5, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=5, offheap=7.8GB, heap=2.5GB]
[19:57:50] Topology snapshot [ver=24, locNode=76308a3b, servers=4, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=6.2GB, heap=2.0GB]
[19:57:56] Topology snapshot [ver=25, locNode=76308a3b, servers=5, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=5, offheap=7.8GB, heap=2.5GB]
[19:57:58] Topology snapshot [ver=26, locNode=76308a3b, servers=4, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=6.2GB, heap=2.0GB]
[19:58:41] Topology snapshot [ver=27, locNode=76308a3b, servers=5, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=5, offheap=7.8GB, heap=2.5GB]
```

Immediately before I identified this problem, I run a minor reconfiguration of the Kubernetes cluster which did not cause pod restarts. Not sure if it could be the cause of the condition in question.

Is it a known problem that has a solution? What should I check (particularly in the logs) which could cast the light on this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Getting affinity for topology version earlier than affinity is calculated` error is caused by a known issue. Here is a JIRA ticket for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8098

No negative effects from this issue has been noticed so far, so pod failures are probably caused by something else.

In Ignite 2.8 there won't be such issue, since implementation of service processor was reworked completely. Here is the related IEP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-17%3A+Oil+Change+in+Service+Grid

Comment: Thank you for the response. In attempt to make my cluster's operation more reliable in the Kubernetes environment, I abandoned the Kubernetes IP finder and deployed Zookeeper. There are still occasional issues but overall the nodes report far fewer errors.

Comment: When is v2.8 expected to be officially released?

Comment: @AlexAvrutin there are no exact plans about the release of 2.8 yet. Usually new versions are released once in 3 months. The previous one, which is 2.7.5, has been released only a week ago. I think, the next one will be 2.8. You can try using one of the [nightly builds](https://ci.ignite.apache.org/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=Releases_NightlyRelease_RunApacheIgniteNightlyRelease&tab=artifacts&guest=1), but I wouldn't recommend going with it any further than development.